# How to test standalone code outside of a scrapy spider?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I can test my xpaths on a HTML body string by running the two lines under (1) below.

But what if I have a local file `myfile.html` whose content is exactly the `body` string. How would I run some standalone code, **outside of a spider**? I am seeking something that is roughly similar to the lines under (2) below.

I am aware that `scrapy shell myfile.html` tests xpaths. My intention is to run some Python code on the response, and hence `scrapy shell` is lacking (or else tedious).

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

# (1)

body = '<html><body><span>Hello</span></body></html>'
print Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()').extract()

# (2)

response = HtmlResponse(url='file:///tmp/myfile.html')
print Selector(response=response).xpath('//span/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [how scrapy tests for link extractors](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/tests/test_linkextractors.py) are implemented.

They use a `get_test_data()` helper to [read a file](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/tests/__init__.py#L31) as bytes,
and then instanciate a `Response` with a fake URL and body set to the bytes read with `get_test_data()`:

```
...
            body = get_testdata('link_extractor', 'sgml_linkextractor.html')
            self.response = HtmlResponse(url='http://example.com/index', body=body)
...
```

Depending on the encoding used for the local HTML files, you may need to pass a non-UTF-8 `encoding` argument to `Response`

Comment: I see. So the url parameter for HtmlResponse (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#htmlresponse-objects) is merely decorative. It triggers neither http:// nor file:// access.

Comment: Right, instantiating HtmlResponse does not call scrapy engine. In scrapy shell, you could call fetch() with a file:// HttpRequest but that would call the engine. It depends what you want to test: xpath/css selectors on HTML bodies,  or the asynchronous engine.

Comment: Note that the url parameter is not decorative, it's used as a base URL if no other base is found in the HTML body. For example, it's used when calling `response.urljoin()`